# Google Sheets Query - Drop down text match

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, statistics

I would like a query on the 'query' tab that searches sheet 'sales' and returns all values if it matches the dropdown selection on the 'query' tab

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UkgIvky_32pPakjCyA6oy1sJxIm50u3npzvasYjGejk/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote string literals in the query statement, like this:

`=query(sales!A1:C, "where '" & B2 & "' <= A and A <= '" & B3 & "' ", 1)`